# How can I bundle a library that includes nativelibraries in my JAR?

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, java-native-library

I made a project in Netbeans 6.8 and added a third-party library which included some nativelibraries. When I made a JAR of my project, only the third-party JAR was included; its nativelibrary was not. Therefore, I am unable to run my project.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native library is loaded just like a resource.  Try placing it in a resources folder.